# JS parameters and Associative arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am Having problems with this JS function. I am trying to pass a String variable and the html element to a JS function, that way I can change other element value.

JS

```
function resetSequence(biz_hrs,form){
var employees= [
{
"esc_hrs":"B"
"esc_resp":5004
"maximun":4
"minimun":1
}
{
"esc_hrs":"B"
"esc_resp":5005
"maximun":4
"minimun":1
}
{
"esc_hrs":"B"
"esc_resp":5006
"maximun":2
"minimun":1
}
{
"esc_hrs":"B"
"esc_resp":5007
"maximun":0
"minimun":0
}
{
"esc_hrs":"B"
"esc_resp":5054
"maximun":3
"minimun":1
},
];
for(var i = 0; i< employees.length; i++){
if(biz_hrs === employees[i].esc_hrs && form.value === employees[i].esc_resp ){
var f = document.escform;
f.sequence.max=employees[i].maximun;
f.sequence.val=employees[i].minimun;
}
}
```

HTML

```
 <select id="p_escalation_resp_i" name="p_escalation_resp_i" class="validate[required]" onChange="resetSequence('B',this)">
<option value="5004">Database</option>
<option value="5005" selected >Application</option>
<option value="5006">Network Connectivity</option>
<option value="5007">Operating System Hardware</option>
<option value="5054">TEST</option>
      </select>

<input type="number" name="p_escalation_sequence_i" id="sequence"   value="1" step="1" min="0" max=""  selected />
```

my question is if the Char parameter B is good and if the for cicle is also good

Comment: Why are you escaping so much, just pass `'B'` in normally!

Comment: I saw in other blog answer that you have to do that??

Comment: Only if your quotes are going to cancel one another out, in your case they wont.

Comment: And do you see any problem with the for or if strucures I correct the B quotation but still not working?

Comment: There's one part of the question I don't understand: "if the Char parameter B is good and if the for cicle is also good". Can you explain further?

Comment: Yes, then change min and max of the sequence number html element in form, this way I can change escalation resp and the JS will adapt the min and max depending of escalation resp

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but I can infer that you want to change the max and min value of your sequence input, right?

The condition:

```
if(biz_hrs === employees[i].esc_hrs && form.value === employees[i].esc_resp ){
```

Always return false because `form.value` is String and `employees[i].esc_resp` is integer.

Then try to quote the `employees[i].esc_resp` values in your array definition:

```
var employees= [
{
"esc_hrs":"B",
"esc_resp":"5004",
"maximun":4,
"minimun":1
},
{
"esc_hrs":"B"
"esc_resp":"5005"
"maximun":4
"minimun":1
},
{
"esc_hrs":"B",
"esc_resp":"5006",
"maximun":2,
"minimun":1
},
{
"esc_hrs":"B",
"esc_resp":"5007",
"maximun":0,
"minimun":0
},
{
"esc_hrs":"B",
"esc_resp":"5054",
"maximun":3,
"minimun":1
}
];
```

Pay attention to comma signs (,) and quotes (" ").

The complete code that works for me:

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
   <select id="p_escalation_resp_i" name="p_escalation_resp_i" class="validate[required]" onChange="resetSequence('B',this);">
   <option value="5004">Database</option>
   <option value="5005" selected >Application</option>
   <option value="5006">Network Connectivity</option>
   <option value="5007">Operating System Hardware</option>
   <option value="5054">TEST</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="p_escalation_sequence_i" id="sequence"   value="1" step="1" min="0" max=""  selected />

<script>
function resetSequence(biz_hrs,form){

var employees= [
{
"esc_hrs":"B",
"esc_resp":"5004",
"maximun":4,
"minimun":1
},
{
"esc_hrs":"B",
"esc_resp":"5005",
"maximun":4,
"minimun":1
},
{
"esc_hrs":"B",
"esc_resp":"5006",
"maximun":2,
"minimun":1
},
{
"esc_hrs":"B",
"esc_resp":"5007",
"maximun":0,
"minimun":0
},
{
"esc_hrs":"B",
"esc_resp":"5054",
"maximun":3,
"minimun":1
}
];

for(var i = 0; i< employees.length; i++){
 if(biz_hrs === employees[i].esc_hrs && form.value === employees[i].esc_resp ){
  var f = document.getElementById("sequence");
  f.max=employees[i].maximun;
  f.val=employees[i].minimun;
  break;
 }
}

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```